# Copy information CSV Files to SQL Database (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to using Data Factory and what I want to do is to copy the information from several CSV files (storage accounts) to a SQL Server database to the respective tables already created. If for example I have 4 CSV files there should be 4 tables.

I have been testing some activities, for example the "Copy Data", but that would cause me to create the same amount of datasets and if for example there were 15 tables, that would be too many datasets.

I want to make it dynamic but I can't figure out how to do it.

How do you suggest me to do this, any example please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either, you can use wildcard to read all files together which are under same blob container.
Once, you read that then in mapping you can add identifier to determine which columns belongs to which table through which you can identify and import data into resp tables OR You can use foreach loop to read all files from blob container and import data into resp table based on file name.

I had created below article to copy data from sql database to sql database for beginners, you can refer it for some initial level setting.

[Azure Data Factory (ADF) Overview For Beginners](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-data-factory-adf-overview-for-beginners/)

Comment: I did it with "Get Metadata" and "forEach (activity: copy data)", and I can insert the data. But how do I get the "ID" of an insert to insert it as a foreign key in another table?